# How to access code outside of current folder directory?

Tags: python, visual-studio, directory

I want to access my 'utils' folder that is outside of the current directory that my code is in. How do I access the files and functions within that file?

For example, I am trying to access functions in file_to_access.py from 00_label_data.py.

[image]

I tried doing this but it still is not working and says 'no module found'

[image]

What is the correct method for doing this method?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell from the screen shots, as the display isn't quite as descriptive as I've like.  However, the main suspicion is at

```
... import file_to_access.py
```

There is no such module: the *module* name is merely `file_to_access`; you supplied the file name.  Also, I suspect that you will want

```
import mbl.code.utils.file_to_access
```

to properly activate your reference in line 8.